# On what conditions would an alien's civilization be completely peacefull?

Tags: internal-consistency, aliens, civilization

I have been asking numerous questions about alien civilizations when it comes to lacking things like greed, money or violence. The reason I'm doing this is because I'm designing an alien species which is completely peaceful with its own race and its environment. So my question is, how could a civilization develop if it was peaceful from the beginning?

I know that many of you would say that "this is my world and I should do what I want" but I want my world to be at least a bit realistic, and I could really use some help from professionals. Now, I have thought of a few things that may have pushed my race of aliens to be peaceful:

• First of all, my species evolved and develop civilization on a small island in the middle of an ocean. So at the beginning, there was only one small tribe that lived happily on its island eating fruits, insects and fishes (sidenote* there weren't any large herbivores for them to hunt or domesticate). Because of that, there was barely ever conflict in the island, because it was just one nation. If there were other nations then... well, most likely there would have been conflict and thus war. Plus, there were no other tribes in the rest of the world because as I mentioned at first, they all started at a small island.

• Secondly, the females of this species were considered superior. I'm not an expert, but I feel like women have a less violent nature than males, so making them be superior seemed logical to me in order for there to be more peace. (Again, I'm not sure, don't judge)

• Third, nature was like a goddess to them, even as they kept advancing. This sort of religion kept them away from causing mass destructions to their environment. It's not like they didn't alter their planet's ecosystem, but they never hunted other animals for fun and never took to much of what their world provided them. In essence, they thought that they were part of the other lifeforms in the world and that they should use what the world provides them with consent.

•Four: destroying the ecosystem wasn't an option anyways. Even with their religion there were some who supposed that they should do more massive changes to their planet but in term they could be harmful to nature. But this wasn't always easy due to the planets biosphere. Example someone wants to clear out the forest in which they live to keep predators out, while this worked it brought a problem. Without the trees to cover them they were an easy target for large aerial predators. Another example is when it comes to resources, let's say that in this species future they need metal and other minerals in order to build things like rockets or skyscrapers etc. While the best way to take a large amount of these metals was to create large mines, which would probably destroy a few forested areas, there was another problem. You see, in this world, there were large worm-like creatures that were feeding upon minerals. Since the people, were digging more and more of them, the "worms" sensed all this food and came to feast upon it. Now, many of you would say that the best course of action would be for them to drive other creatures into extinction so that they can develop, and I agree. But because of this whole nature religion thing, the decided not to. Instead they found new and better solutions to their problems. Basically, they were trying to find methods of keeping their effect on the world low.

• Another thing to keep in mind is the way they started producing energy. You see, on their planet there are plants and trees that can produce a sort of electric sort and thus energy. So the people had a renewable and sophisticated energy source.

•Lastly, they had a knowledge-based economy system. What do I mean by that? Well, to put it simply, if you wanted to buy something you had to learn something new. This something could be either an information or a new skill. Now each person had its own personal file, where what he or she had learned was written down. Not only did that economic system, make people more eager to learn, it also made crime a thing of the past. I mean, how can you steel knowledge? You can't.

Those are my speculations on how my race turned out to be peaceful. Now I'm just asking if these would really work and if anything else needs editing.

Comment: Plants have no needs or wants, grow peacefully on islands, and eat local fauna. Are you describing plants? (although arguably plants kill other plants, but that seems only incidental and not an active decision)

Comment: One thing for sure is that they must never develop anything that looks like a blue Volkswagen beetle.

Comment: "*I feel like women have a less violent nature than males*".  There's a **60:40** chance that a random adult male will be more violent than a random adult female.  That still leaves a whole lot of violent females.

Comment: "*the females of this species were considered superior.*"  What does "superior" mean?

Comment: @RonJohn The statistics also can't distinguish between a less violent *nature* and a less violent *nurture*, if you will. Culture and upbringing play a big role.

Comment: Lastly, on "*a small island in the middle of an ocean*, there's just **no room** to "*(keep) advancing*".

Comment: @Cadence according to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK207258/ a lot of human violence is *nature*.  Look also at young boys: raise him as anti-violently as you want, but he'll still knock down his blocks and laugh.

Comment: The whole thing about nature keeping them in check wouldn't work. Similar things happened here on Earth, and if your aliens are anything like humans, they will find a way to "tame" nature.

Comment: "I feel like women have a less violent nature than males" --- I would love to agree, but you have clearly never watched Geraldo, Divorce Court or Youtube.

Comment: I believe most species evolved to survive in their environments and only certain traits would be inherited. Certainly you could have a peaceful race because they never needed to resolve conflicts because everyone needs were fulfilled ( you can search up the monkeys that solve problems with sex ). However this also means that they likely wouldn't develop the same intelligence that we have because they never needed it. If your species has everything given to them, they won't evolve to be intelligent because there is no need for it. It would be a waste or energy. 1/2

Comment: Next, generating usable electricity is not going to work naturally. Plants wouldn't evolve that way to act like solar power generators because of the materials required to efficiently transfer electricity and piezoelectric materials require movement to generate electricity and this occurs on a very small scale. Thats wasted energy to create inefficient energy. At best, you could develop some sort of biological computer system instead. Maybe there is a tree or plant that reacts to a touch and when you poke it it moves in a certain way. Chain them together to create different gates and logic 2/?

Comment: If they have predators, they won't evolve to be the leading race. A predator means they aren't at the top of the food chain and that another species is going to be gathering energy in a much more efficient manner. A herbivore (because you don't want violence which I assume killing hunting implies) is going to evolve to survive a predator. Intelligence (at the slow evolutionary pace) isn't going to help much. Camouflage, speed, endurance, defense weapons(horns) and size would play a much larger and  provide a more immediate impact. Intelligence helps much more with hunting and so do tools. 3/?

Comment: Now onto the metals that you need to advance your society. You don't have them. Your worms basically eat them all up somehow. Your basically saying that your race won't develop buildings or technology. Firstly without metals, electricity is going to be useless and any natural system is going to end up much slower than a computer. Your also going to lack ways to extract and process fuel for spaceships, let alone the materials to build the spaceship, perform the necessary calculations. Your even less likely to develop writing because you don't want to harm nature (no storing knowledge). 4/?

Comment: Not harming nature usually means you have no long term storage. People are restricted to what they remember and this is already going to be hard because memory isn't perfect. Stealing knowledge is pretty dam easy if you need to exchange it for goods/services. Give them the good. Get the knowledge, Steal back the good. Now I have stolen your knowledge. Having an economy will also lead to conflicts because it means you have needs and wants that you can't satisfy yourself and this leads to conflicts when multiple have the same need/want which can only be satisfied by less individuals. 5/5

Comment: @elemtilas, or being in a shop at the beginning of sales season...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the entirety of the species is a single colony, then nearly all of the aggressive behaviours that humans have simply wouldn't be present in them. Since a lack of infighting means less violent individuals are preffered, they have the most offspring, and the gentle traits propagate quickly in the populace. They may even develop an aversion to fighting, where conflict actively causes their body large amounts of stress or releases calming chemicals to make them stop.

Although large predators means they will have more incentive to live in small groups as opposed to a single large one. I suggest instead, make them breed less often in favor of smarter children, eliminate predators so that they can live freely, and then make the world rich in food, but only about enough to support the colony. Lack of pressures to evolve will prevent them from developing their resources until they are smart enough to actively question the world around them, with individuals who are dumb die in accidents from being stupid.

So there you have it, a non confrontational alien species that evolved to live within a fixed environment, diverted resources to being better at living instead of having more babies, and eventually became intelligent.

Answer (score -1):

They did not evolve from predators.

Make them vegetarian and value living in harmony with their environment.

Comment: "*Make them vegetarian and value living in harmony with their environment.*" There's no reason why vegetarians can't employ slash-and-burn farming.

Comment: No reason herbivores can't fight within themselves or against predators.